# Python: Plot only the difference of two datasets y-values when they have slightly different x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

Consider two different datasets.

The first looks like this:

```
0.033333284161002015    51.0
0.06666656832200403 0.0
0.09999985248300605 0.0
0.13333313664400806 0.0
0.16666642080501007 0.0
0.1999997049660121  0.0
0.2333329891270141  0.0
0.2666662732880161  0.0
0.29999955744901813 0.0
0.33333284161002014 0.0
0.36666612577102214 0.0
0.3999994099320242  0.0
```

and the second like this:

[image]

The first column gives a timestamp. In the first dataset time is measured in seconds, in the second dataset time is measured in milli seconds. Now, what I want to do is the following: Whenever time is more or less equal for both datasets, safe the values in the right column.

For example: `0.33333`seconds from the first dataset is more or less equal to `336` milliseconds from the second dataset.

Why do I want to do this? When I plot both datasets in just one figure, the result is this: 
[image]

But I am only interested in the difference between these two stem plots at times where both plots are drawn.

I was hoping to be able to achieve this goal with the following python code:

```
CmpTimestamp = []
for index,element in enumerate(1stColumn1stDataset):
    for idx,el in enumerate(1stColumn2ndDataset):
        if truncate(element*100)/100 == truncate(el/10)/100: 
            CmpTimestamp.append(truncate(element*100)/100)
```

But for some reason my `CmpTimestamp` list is empty.

Comment: This sounds more like a  data preparation question than a plotting question. Is that correct? I recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples